# Unexpected alert open error even though alert is expected: Selenium Serenity BDD

Tags: java, selenium, serenity-bdd

I am testing that if signup is failed, an alert should say "User already exist"
But I'm getting  "org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : This user already exist.}" even though this is the expected alert

### My code below:

```
public String alertTextVerify(){
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        return alert.getText();
    }

public void verifyIfUserExist() {
        try {
            String signupFailedAlertText = alertTextVerify();
            assertEquals("This user already exist.", signupFailedAlertText);
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
            fail("Alert not shown");
        } catch (UnhandledAlertException e) {
            fail("UnhandledAlertException");
        }}
```

Comment: You need to handle the alert before catching UnhandledAlertException.

Comment: It is handled in the alertTextVerify() @pburgr

Comment: these exceptions are a little confusing because they happen on the next webdriver action.  Most webdriver actions will first check for an unexpected alert.  You might want to set the "unhandledPromptBehavior" of the driver to "ignore":  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/capabilities/shared/#unhandledpromptbehavior  The default behavior is to "dismiss and notify".  The "notify" part is throwing the exception you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try one thing.

Here as I understand, from ui perspective, alert is still open and not handled, so what you can do is

```
public String alertTextVerify(){
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        String alertText = alert.getText();
        alert.dismiss(); //it is important you close alert or do something about it. 
        return alertText;
    }
```

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html#accept()

Comment: This isn't working. Now the alert gets open even before Send message button is clicked. @swapyonubuntu